# ¿como puedo relacionar la tabla ciudad con empleado y empresa sin tener una relacion circular?

Tags: base-de-datos, modelorelacional

estoy tratando de relacionar ciudad con empleado y obra con ciudad pero al relacionarlas se me genera una relación circular, no encuentro una forma ma de relacionar lado que la obra tiene una ciudad donde es construida y el empleado[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] es de una ciudad

Comment: Si le  pones  el  `Id` de ciudad tanto a `Empleado` como  a  `Obra`  me parece que no se está haciendo una relación circular.

Comment: como? no te entiendo

Comment: Ciudad es una tabla "catálogo" y entidad fuerte según entiendo. Si es así todas sus relaciones serían `1 ... *`, lo cual no genera una relación circular pues ciudad no depende de nadie, pero sí hay algunas entidades débiles o tablas (como cliente y obra) que dependen de ciudad. Yo tampoco veo relación circular. Ciudad es una entidad fuerte.

Comment: En  todo caso deberías explicar  mejor tu modeo. Por lo poco que  se puede  apreciar  tiene  muchas relaciones N-N y  eso  es medio raro. Ahora tu tabla `Ciudad`solo tiene un atributo que es  el nombre, por lo tanto, no veo porque no  agregarle a `Empleado`  un atributo `IdCiudad` asociado al `Id` de la Tabla Ciudad. Asimismo, en la tabla `Obra` agregar un atributo `IdCiudad`. Por otro lado, todo está en función  a que se refiere `Obra` y al ambito que le quieres dar a `Ciudad`  cuando se trata de una  `obra`  y cuando se trata de  `empleado`; pudieran ser diferentes.

Comment: No hay ninguna relación circular,  los empleados viven en una ciudad y las obras se realizan en una ciudad, que ambas entidades tengan una relación con la misma tabla en este caso es absolutamente lógico.